# Access API key in javascript from django settings.py

Tags: django, django-templates, google-places-api

I am trying to pass an API key for google places from my settings.py file to a JS script. Should I expect to be able to access the variable in the JS script this way, or is there a better approach?

```
    # settings.py

    api_key = 123456HYTYTY


    # views.py

    args['api_key'] = settings.api_key
    return render(request, 'template_example.html', args)
    

    # template.html

    {% block js %}
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ api_key }}&libraries=places" defer></script>
    {% endblock js %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an answer, but I would appreciate comments on whether it is considered secure, in so much that my api_key will not be visible anywhere?

```
# docker-compose.yml
GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY=123456HYTYTY


# settings.py

api_key = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY')


# views.py

args['api_key'] = settings.api_key
return render(request, 'template_example.html', args)


# Template.html 
{% block js %}

{{ api_key|json_script:"api_key" }}

<script>

const api_key = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('api_key').textContent);
const google_api_script = document.createElement('script');
google_api_script.setAttribute('src','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + api_key + '&libraries=places');
document.head.appendChild(google_api_script);

</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Comment: Since your API key will be in the source code of your HTML, it will of course be visible by anyone having a look at your page's source code. You should secure your API key by restricting its usage to your domain name and specific API. You can do this from the Google Cloud Console. For testing purposes you can use an API key that doesn't have the domain restriction. Just be sure to never make that key public, so no one else can use it.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I ended up going with!